# Cloth simulation acting wonky in render. Correct in viewport

Tags: baking, cloth-simulation, parent

I've baked a cloth simulation and parented it to another object. The animation looks right in the viewport but when I render it, it jumps to the right on the X axis and then gradually floats to the left.

Animation starts at frame 118. The initial jump changes based on what frame i start the bake on: closer to 0 means further to the right.

Here's the viewport render to show what the animation is supposed to look like.

https://gfycat.com/victoriousoldfashionedhydatidtapeworm

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: it's a webm though. I'm not sure if it's supported. Also you don't need to see it to underdstand the question. edit: It's not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to see what it is doing in the final render. However, normally when something like this happens, either you have a subdivision surface modifier on the object with cloth and you have settings set differently on the view port than the render. This would apply into the same concept as other modifiers that you could have on the object with cloth simulation. It does not sound like subsurface. But, works the same depending on the mod. Obviously, something that is checked on for render in your scene and is set different to view port is affecting your final results.

Comment: The object has only a Vertex Weight Proximity and Cloth Modifier on the stack. I even tried deleting the Force Fields after baking,  and disabling all Field Weights with no success. Also it seems whenever i hit render the result is different even for the same frame and without doing any changes. Any ideas what could cause the randomness? I found a workaround which is a pain in the butt. Rendering each frame individually and saving it gives me the results I want. I had a similar problem on another project but I thought it was just animation-nodes related, this one however doesnt use ani-nodes.

Comment: Are you rendering images in a stack? That could solve the issue if what you said is a work around. It is far more sensible to do that anyways because rendering in batch as a movie file bugs every so often. Rendering with images and then compiling them into a sequencer with Blender or Davinci, etc. is what every studio does. I would recommend it if that is the fix that you found.

Comment: You should also check that you are baking with a disk cache, otherwise your animation data for the bake will not be stored for a render. That is also what it could be.

Comment: I render it as a PNG sequence. And I also tried to use the Disk cache, but it doesn't change the weird behavior.

Comment: Well, what I would do at this point is to clear everything that has to do with the cloth simulation back out and bring it back in and set it back up from a new import and keep a careful eye on everything that you are doing.